# creating KNN algo in R self code using euclidean distance

Tags: r, distance, knn

as part of a homework assignment, I need to write my code for KNN regression with euclidean_distance.
my thought was to :

1. create a function for euclidean_distance.
2. compute the distance between all the data points to the new data point using euclidean_distance.
3. sort smallest to largest distance and choose K neighbors from the ordered list.
4. compute the average to predict the Y value for X.
   I managed to do the first part-euclidean_distance. Then I got stuck on how to code the algorithm afterward.

this is my code

```r
euclidean_distance = function(a, b){
  if(length(a) == length(b)){
    sqrt(sum((a-b)^2))} 
  else{
    stop('Vectors must be of the same length')
  }
}
```

would be thankful for any help :)

tried to code euclidean_distance  but unfortunately didn't know how to continue in terms of coding

the final function should look like :

```
my_knn(s,k,x)
```

s=
x- new data point

Answer (score 0):

I found this really helpfull post of creating the `KNN` algorithm from scratch: https://anderfernandez.com/en/blog/code-knn-in-r/. First you create the `euclidean distance` function using this code:

```
euclidean_distance = function(a, b){
  #  We check that they have the same number of observation
  if(length(a) == length(b)){
    sqrt(sum((a-b)^2))  
  } else{
    stop('Vectors must be of the same length')
  }
}
```

After you create the algorithm from scratch using this code:

```
nearest_neighbors = function(x,obs, k, FUN, p = NULL){
  
  # Check the number of observations is the same
  if(ncol(x) != ncol(obs)){
    stop('Data must have the same number of variables')
  }
  
  # Calculate distance, considering p for Minkowski
  if(is.null(p)){
    dist = apply(x,1, FUN,obs)  
  }else{
    dist = apply(x,1, FUN,obs,p)
  }
  
  # Find closest neighbours
  distances = sort(dist)[1:k]
  neighbor_ind = which(dist %in% sort(dist)[1:k])
  
  if(length(neighbor_ind)!= k){
    warning(
      paste('Several variables with equal distance. Used k:',length(neighbor_ind))
    )
  }
  
  ret = list(neighbor_ind, distances)
  return(ret)
}
```

Now let's use the `iris` dataset as an example. In the function above from `KNN`, `x` means the dataset (in this case `iris`), `obs` is the observation you want to find the nearest neighbors, `k` is the number of neighbors and `FUN` means the formula you use to calculate the distances between the points. In this case `euclidean`. You can use the following code as an example:

```
x = iris[1:(nrow(iris)-1),]
obs = iris[nrow(iris),]

ind = nearest_neighbors(x[,1:4], obs[,1:4],4, euclidean_distance)[[1]]
as.matrix(x[ind,1:4])
```

Where `obs` are the observations to find its closest neighbors:

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
150          5.9           3          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

Output of matrix gives the `k` number of closest neighbors:

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
102          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9
128          6.1         3.0          4.9         1.8
139          6.0         3.0          4.8         1.8
143          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9
```

Comment: yes i saw that post. but i was not sure how could i change the code so I would calculate euclidean_distance between the X elements of S to the new data point.  S for example looks like[[1,2],[3,4]]